# sudoku backtracking issue c++

Tags: c++, sudoku, recursive-backtracking

This is my main recursive function that doesn't seem to work at all and has weirder behavior than I would expect. What am I doing wrong? P.S. The function below is part of a class. Will include the rest of the code if needed..

```
bool solve()
{

    if(isSolved()){return true;}

    for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<9; j++)
        {
            if(grid[i][j] > 0)
            {
                continue;
            }


            for(int k=1; k<10; k++)
            {
                grid[i][j] = k;

                if(tryVal(i,j,k) == true && solve())
                {
                    return true;
                }

                grid[i][j] = 0;

            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I dont see anything wrong here except maybe `tryVal(i,j,k)` following the assignment `grid[i][j] = k;`. Anyway you should try to debug your code.

Comment: I don't see any obvious problem. You should use a debugger to examine your program's behavior as it runs and determine where the unexpected behavior first appears.

Comment: Can you please post the definition for the function tryVal(i,j,k) and isSolved()?

Comment: Is it possible for this function to ever return? I don't think so.

Comment: How many cells are filled in initially? And what behavior exactly do you observe?

Comment: Your problem is either in if(tryVal(i,j,k) == true && solve()) or in the body of isSolved(). I am afraid we need to see the body of that function and to know which is the final result/behaviour of the computation to give you a useful advice (ps. do you get a full blank matrix as output?)

Comment: I would feel safer with `if( tryVal(i,j,k) && solve())` or with `if(( tryVal(i,j,k) == true ) &&  solve())`. What exactly does it mean: `doesn't seem to work at all` ...  did you try to debug?

Comment: btw the solver can be iterative too may be this [Sudoku solving in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51160251/2521214) might give some inspiration.