# Javascript - How can I optimize my sudoku?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, optimization, solver, sudoku

I want to create a sudoku solver, but I noticed with an expert level sudoku, it took several seconds to display the result ...
Here's a piece of my code:

```js
function possible(board, y, x, n) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (board[y][i] === n || board[i][x] === n) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    const xSquare = Math.floor(x / 3) * 3;
    const ySquare = Math.floor(y / 3) * 3;

    for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (board[ySquare + i][xSquare + j] === n) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function solve(board) {
    for (let y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
        for (let x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
            if (board[y][x] === 0) {
                for (let n = 1; n <= 9; n++) {
                    if (possible(board, y, x, n)) {
                        board[y][x] = n;
                        if (solve(board)) {
                            return board;
                        }
                    }
                }
                board[y][x] = 0;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return board;
}
```

My function possible() is to see if the x and y axis do not have the same number, and if the square (3x3) does not have the same number as the current box.

My function solver() function is used to see if there are no more 0s in my array and if the possible function possible() me return true.

I think my problem comes from the double for in the possible () function, it starts over the whole array but I don't know how to make it stop at the case ...

Comment: see [Sudoku solving in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51160251/2521214) the solver is applying solving rules (no trial and error) and fill in what can (for medium difficulty sudoku it usually solves the whole thing)... once it is stuck you need to brute force the rest (which with backtracking might also use the rules again...)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are recursively brute-forcing every possible combination. I don't have any magic solution to bypass the brute-forcing. However we can make the brute force smarter.

Current approach:

- You are going over every not-filled space. approx 70-75 in the first iteration, one less in each subsequent one.
- For every such field, you try to fill it with every possible number (up to 9 options, usually less)
- Then you call yourself recursively on a board with one less filled field
- Until you stumble on the first possible solution.

The number of operations you are currently doing is something between 9^(81-positions filled at start) (upper bound, meaning bruteforcing every option without ever pruning) to something a lot lower - e.g. the more values you have filled, the more often you will fail and prune the branch of the possibility tree.
The actual count will be something like: 7 * 7 * 7 * ... * 6 * 6 * ... * ... until done.

So the first possible improvement is smarter prunning. Board is possible if and only if:

- All its fields are filled
- All non-filled fields have more than zero possible options.

Currently you are checking only the to-be-filled field, which means
that you can create boards that will later get instantly rejected. This creates a lot of unnecessary branches. A bit of pseudocode to illustrate:

```
 function possibleCount(board, x, y) {
     /*code to compute available options - e.g. number 0-9*/
     return count
}

function boardPossible(board,x, y, n) {
   board[x][y] = n
   foreach (field in board) {
       if (possibleCount(field) == 0) {
          //if there is any field that is invalidated by inserting
          //the value, we are stuck and we can prune the branch.
          return false 
       }
   }
}
```

This seems like a lot of extra computing, however we are making a tradeoff here. We will take a bit more time each and every step(computing the possible board options) for pruning most of the branches as early as possible.
Furhermore, you can shift the computation from the initial 7 * 7 * 7 ... * 6 * 6 options to something more reasonable by simply **filling in the fields with least options first**.
This will lead to failing sooner, which in turns means less options to cover.

Last bit of optimization that comes to my mind is that the counting of available options for every field can be sped up by having a list of available options for every row, column and square.

- When updating a field, simply remove the new value from [row, column, square].
- When checking for an availability of a field, check if it is available for each of the [row, column, square]

This will remove much of the overhead introduced by the abovementioned board checking.
Unfortunately I'm currently at work, but if I have time, I will later on try to do some benchmarks.

Comment: Thanks to you for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

> I think my problem comes from the double for in the possible () function

That looks fine to me. Double for loops can be really slow, but in this case, each loop only makes 3 iterations, so the inner body is only executed 9 times. That's not such a big deal.

There are faster ways to implement the "possibility check" though. For example by keeping track of which values are used in each row, column, and block. If that is stored as bit masks, it is easy to compute (with just a couple of bitmath operations) which values are possible for a given cell: no loops at all.

The main technique you can use to speed up your solver is adding iterative constraint propagation: iteratively look for cells that can be filled in directly without search, for example [Naked Singles](https://www.learn-sudoku.com/lone-singles.html) and [Hidden Singles](https://www.learn-sudoku.com/hidden-singles.html). In my experience, propagation makes the biggest difference between a slow solver and a fast one, but of course an efficient implementation also matters.