# How can I store the occurences of a number in a sudoku subgrid (3x3)?

Tags: c, algorithm, sudoku, find-occurrences

So I've been trying to store all the occurences of numbers from 1 to 9 in an array. I've succeeded for rows and columns and tried to apply the same logic for subgrids of 3x3 but to no avail.

My sudoku grid is a 2D array 9x9 (purposefully put two 9 in the same subgrid to trigger the error message).

```
0, 9, 0, 0, 0,,0, 0, 1, 0,
9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5,
8, 0, 5, 4, 0, 9, 2, 0, 7,
0, 0, 0, 3, 9, 6, 0, 0, 0,
0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0,
0, 0, 0, 2, 7, 8, 0, 0, 0,
3, 0, 7, 8, 0, 2, 5, 0, 9,
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3,
0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0
```

Here's the code of my function:

```
int no_conflict_3x3(int sudoku[N][N]){
    int occurrence[N] = {0};
        for (int l=0; l<3;l++){
            for(int k = 0; k<3; k++){
                for (int i=0+3*k; i<3*k; i++){
                    for(int j=0+3*l; j<3*l; j++){
                    printf("%d", sudoku[i][j]);
                        switch(sudoku[i][j]){
                case 1:
                    occurrence[0]++;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    occurrence[1]++;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    occurrence[2]++;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    occurrence[3]++;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    occurrence[4]++;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    occurrence[5]++;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    occurrence[6]++;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    occurrence[7]++;
                    break;
                case 9:
                    occurrence[8]++;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        
        for (int o = 0; o<N; o++){
                printf("o = %d : occurence=%d | ", o+1, occurrence[o]); //DEBUG
            if (occurrence[o]>1){
                printf("Not a valid sudoku grid.\n");
                return 1;}
            else occurrence[o] = 0;
            }
            printf("\n");
         
     }
     }
        
        return 0;
}
```

and here's the result after one iteration (for one line):

```
o = 1 : occurence=0 | o = 2 : occurence=0 | o = 3 : occurence=0 | o = 4 : occurence=0 | o = 5 : occurence=0 | o = 6 : occurence=0 | o = 7 : occurence=0 | o = 8 : occurence=0 | o = 9 : occurence=0 |
```

I don't know why my variable occurrence is stuck at 0. Any help please?

Comment: Your loops does nothing: `for (int i=0+3*k; i<3*k; i++){` i goes from 3*k while i <3*k ?!?!?!?! Also for j: `for(int j=0+3*l; j<3*l; j++){`

Comment: What's the output of `printf("%d", sudoku[i][j]);`?

Comment: @pmg nothing at all... I've put this printf after my ```switch``` loop, is it correct?

Comment: @yk87 Yes, but you don't enter the loop ever. See my answer.

Comment: You might consider using a matrix library. That would allow you to store the cell entries in a 9x9 matrix and easily examine specific rows, columns and 3x3 sub-matrices. Alternatively, as there are only nine 3x3 groups, you could store their row and column offsets in a 3x3 array`groups`. For example, `groups[1][2] = [[[3,6],[3,7],[3,8]], [[4,6],[4,7],[4,8]], [[5,6],[5,7],[5,8]]]`.

Comment: see [Sudoku solving in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51160251/2521214) I use bitmasks for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 ignored loops since you loop from the start to the start.
Your i and j loops are like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 0; ++i){...}
```

It does nothing.

Change

```
for (int i=0+3*k; i<3*k; i++){
    for(int j=0+3*l; j<3*l; j++){
```

to:

```
for (int i=3*k; i<3*(k+1); i++){
    for(int j=3*l; j<3*(l+1); j++){
```

Note the `i < 3*k` is changed to `i < 3*(k + 1)`, similarly for j

On the other hand, you count the 'golbal occurence', but you need them in every 3x3 subgrid...

Answer (score 0):

1. We need to reset `occurrences[]` for every grid.
2. We don't need to count the occurrences of a number, if it's a duplicate then we've an invalid grid (3x3)
3. We don't need `switch` case, numbers themselves are good indexes into `occurrences[]`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define N 9

int no_conflict_3x3 (int sudoku[N][N]) {
    // grids 3 x 3
    for (int gri = 1; gri < N; gri += 3) { // grid row id
        for (int gci = 1; gci < N; gci += 3) { // grid column id
            int occurrence[N +1] = {0}; // +1 to use  index [9]
            for (int ri = gri -1; ri <= (gri +1); ++ri) {
                for (int ci = gci -1; ci <= (gci +1); ++ci)
                    if (sudoku[ri][ci] && occurrence[sudoku[ri][ci]]) {
                        printf ("Invalid Grid, Grid Center [%d][%d].\n", gri, gci);
                        return 1;
                    } else
                        occurrence[sudoku[ri][ci]] = 1;
            }
            for (int gi = 1; gi <= N; ++gi)
                printf ("%d: occ %d | ", gi, occurrence[gi]);
            putchar ('\n');
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


int main (void) {
    int sudoku [N][N] = {
        {0, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
        {9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5},
        {8, 0, 5, 4, 0, 9, 2, 0, 7},
        {0, 0, 0, 3, 9, 6, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 2, 7, 8, 0, 0, 0},
        {3, 0, 7, 8, 0, 2, 5, 0, 9},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3},
        {0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 5}
    };
    int status = no_conflict_3x3(sudoku);

    return 0;
}
```